# How to fix this update method in my Express Server to account for an array in a Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am building a REST Api with express, mongodb and mongoose. As a part of my schema I have stated that I want an array to hold a list of values. I am unable to use postman to add or update the values in the array. I am basically wondering why this isn't working and what would be the best practice for this type of situation.

Here is my mongoose Schema

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Quote = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    quote: [String],
    date_submitted: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Quote', Quote);
```

As Stated I have an Array setup to hold multiple quotes.

Here is the method for adding a quote to the mongoDB:

```
    let quote = new Quotes({
        name: req.body.name,
        quote: req.body,
    });
    quote
        .save()
        .then(quote => {
            res.status(200).send('adding new quote successful');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new quote failed' + err);
        });
});
```

This does add a record to the DB but I am not sure if this method is best practice.

This is the update method that is NOT working at all

```
router.post('/update/:id', (req, res) => {
    // Quotes.findOneAndUpdate({ name: req.body.name }, { $push: { quote: req.body.quote } });
    Quotes.findById(req.params.id, function(err, quote) {
        if (!quote) {
            res.status(404).send('Data is not found');
        } else {
            quote.author = req.body.name;
            quote.quotes = { $push: { quote: req.body.quote } };
            quote.date_submitted = req.body.date_submitted;

            quote
                .save()
                .then(quote => {
                    res.json('quote updated');
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.status(400).send('Update not possible' + ' ' + err);
                });
        }
    });
});
```

You can see that I tried to do the findOneAndUpdate method but it did not push the values into the array like it should. When I submit my POST request from Postman I do not get an error but when I check the Database the Array value remains the same. Any help on this would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try pushing the quote to the `quote.quote` using a simple [array#push](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/push) , then saving the document. 
   `quote.quote.push(req.body.quote)`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this! That does allow me add values to the array in the database on the update method.